# How to get only characters highlighted from a string in php?

Tags: php

I have a string and some words, i want to highlight those words which match with string, and also i want to print only those words which are highlighted, like if apple matches, then only apple must be printed.

```
$string = "apple computer";

$keyword = "apple,orange,bike";
```

I am using the following function to highlight specific characters in a string.

```
$str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<span style='color:orange;'>$0</span>",$string);
```

The problem is I want to show only those characters which are highlighted, currently it shows all the characters.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would meet your need.

```
$string = " apple computer orange";
$keywords = "apple, orange";

$exp_kwd = explode(",", $keywords);

$res = "<span style='color:orange;'>";

foreach($exp_kwd as $val){

    if(strpos($string, trim($val))){

       $res .=  $val." ";
    }
}
$res = $res."</span>";

echo $res;
```

Comment: yes i have tried, i want to show only highlighted character not other, means if apple is highlighted then only apple should be print out, not other

Comment: do you want to remove the else?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this also will work

```
$string = "apple computer orange tested";
$keyword = "apple,orange,bike,tested";

$pattern="/".str_replace(",","/,/",$keyword)."/";
$pattern=explode(",",$pattern);

$string=explode(" ",$string);
$keyword =explode(",",$keyword);

$string=implode(",",(preg_filter($pattern, $keyword, $string)));
echo $string="<span style='color:orange;'>$string</span>";
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to show other words which are not highlighted, just want to show highlighted words

Comment: Please provide sample output

Comment: like if "text" is highlighted then "text" and "texts" should be printed, not other words, in short i just need to show those characters which are highlighted

Comment: Try my answer once again

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Im On  #Here";
$keyword = "#";

$var = strrchr($string,$keyword);
if(empty($var))
{
    echo 'No Occerunce Found';
}
else
{
    echo '<span style="color:orange;">'.$var.'</span>';
}
```

[phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/smj9-byzt)

Comment: what if i have multiple keywords